# Customizing AD Users and Computers snap-in

Tags: active-directory

We are looking at using the ***departmentNumber*** attribute for our users in Active Directory.  Easy enough for admins to edit this attribute using the Attribute Editor tab with AD Users and Computers snap-in.  However, is it possible to put this attribute (or some other attribute) on the *General* or *Organization* tab?  This makes it challenging to create custom MMC's for other support teams.

Currently we are at forest/domain 2008 level.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked into this before, no it is not possible to easily do what you are asking. The easiest solution I came up with is adding a custom command to the right-click context menu, and using it to launch a custom form that contains the fields you want. However, this still isn't the easy and it requires all domain controllers to have the custom code in order for it to work.

If your interested, here's a link that outlines how to create a context menu, as well as a custom form:
http://reddini.blogspot.com/2011/07/additional-active-directory-context.html

In my case, I chose to use a HTA file for my custom form rather than VBA since the layout is much more flexible. The other upside to this is it allows users to easily access any custom AD attributes you may be using.

This what the form I created looks like. We use it to capture 3 pieces of data that AD does not contain fields for. We save these values in custom attributes.

[image]

Here's the code I used for the above window. Of course you'll need to tweak it to your needs. The existing values are passed through the command line args, which the context menu provides.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Information</title>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID='Info'
   SingleInstance='Yes'   
   SysMenu='No'
   MaximizeButton='No'  
   MinimizeButton='No'
   CloseButton='Yes'
   SCROLLFLAT ='No'
    SCROLL='No'
   Border='Thin'
   BORDERSTYLE ='simple' 
   INNERBORDER ='No'
   Caption='Yes'          
   WindowState='Maximized'
   APPLICATIONNAME='Employee Info'
   Icon='%Windir%\explorer.exe'>
</head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
window.resizeTo 410,340
    Dim objSelectedUser
    Dim args

    Sub Window_OnLoad
        args = Split(Info.commandline,"""")
        Birthday.Value = "error"
        HireDate.Value = "error"
        EpicorID.Value = "error"
        Set objSelectedUser = GetObject(args(3))
        EpicorID.Value = objSelectedUser.epicorID
        Birthday.Value = objSelectedUser.employeeBirthday
        HireDate.Value = objSelectedUser.employeeHireDate
    End Sub

        Sub TestSub
            if EpicorID.Value <> "" Then
            objSelectedUser.Put "epicorID",EpicorID.Value
            end if

            if Birthday.Value <> "" Then
            objSelectedUser.Put "EmployeeBirthday",Birthday.Value
            end if  

            if HireDate.Value <> "" Then
            objSelectedUser.Put "EmployeeHireDate",HireDate.Value
            end if
            objSelectedUser.SetInfo

            MsgBox("Settings Saved")
            Close
        End Sub

    Sub CloseWindow
            Close
        End Sub

</SCRIPT>

<body style="background:rgb(242,242,242); font-family:Calibri;">
<center>
<h3>Employee Information</h3>
<p style="border:solid 1px;">Current values are displayed. Enter new values and click "Save" to overwrite the old values. 
Click "Cancel" to exit without making changes. Dates should be entered as MM/DD/YYYY.</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="right">Epicor ID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="EpicorID" size="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Employee Birthdate:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Birthday" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Employee Hire Date</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="HireDate" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <hr>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td align="right"><input id=runbutton  type="button" value="Save" name="run_button"   onClick="TestSub" style="width:100%;"></td>
    <td><input id=runbutton  type="button" value="Cancel/Exit" name="run_button"      onClick="CloseWindow" style="width:100%;"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>


    </body>
```

Comment: that's perfect.  Now all I need to do is learn to code HTA...  :-)

Comment: I updated my original post with the code I used to generate the window. Hope it helps!

Comment: AWESOME!!!!  Thank you so much, that really helps.